# Passing the list of available windows services into an array and prompt user to select the service for activation

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am trying to list all the windows services matching a pattern form linux host and prompt user to select a service for activation. 
I have the below script, but there is a problem. service name has spaces. So, each word after a space is reading as new element in an array. Could you please help in fixing this.

```
#!/bin/bash
host="hhk"
domain="hck"
user="rdama"
pw="Pa$$w0rd"

get_installedversions(){
array=( $(net rpc service list -I $host -U $domain/$user%$pw | grep -i Rpc) )
len=${#array[*]}
echo "The array has length $len members. They are:"

i=0
while [ $i -lt $len ]; do
    echo "$i: ${array[$i]}"
    declare -a "var$i=${array[$i]}"
    let i++
done
echo -n "Enter the service to be activated: "
    read version
}
get_installedversions
echo selected service is ${array[$version]}
net rpc activate service ${array[$version] -I $host -U $domain/$user%$pw
```

Current Output:

```
1) RpcEptMapper    5) RpcLocator     9) (RPC)         13) Procedure
2) "RPC            6) "Remote       10) Locator"      14) Call
3) Endpoint        7) Procedure     11) RpcSs         15) (RPC)"
4) Mapper"         8) Call          12) "Remote
#?
```

Required Output:

```
1) RpcEptMapper            "RPC Endpoint Mapper"
2) RpcLocator              "Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Locator"
3) RpcSs                   "Remote Procedure Call (RPC)"
#?
```

Output from "net rpc service list" command is

```
RpcEptMapper            "RPC Endpoint Mapper"
RpcLocator              "Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Locator"
RpcSs                   "Remote Procedure Call (RPC)"
```

Thanks,
R Dama.

Comment: Try quoting any variables which contain spaces `"${array[$version]}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much simpler using the `select` command. We'll pretend that `net rpc service list` outputs a list of words that won't be unduly affected by word-splitting or pathname expansion.

```
# Just to cut down on some repetition
run_net_rpc () {
  net rpc "$@" -I "$host" -U "$domain/$user%$pw"
}

readarray -t services < <(run_net_rpc service list | grep -i Rpc)
select svc in "${services[@]}"; do
  run_net_rpc activate service "$svc"
  break
done
```

Comment: Still it is same, the out put is like 
1) RpcEptMapper    5) RpcLocator     9) (RPC)         13) Procedure
2) "RPC            6) "Remote       10) Locator"      14) Call
3) Endpoint        7) Procedure     11) RpcSs         15) (RPC)"
4) Mapper"         8) Call          12) "Remote
#?

But, it should be something like

Comment: See the update. This should *almost* work as long as there are no newlines in any of the service names. You also need to remove the quotes from the output of `net`, but is there a way to suppress them in the first place?

Comment: I don't see a way to supress them.

`run_net_rpc service list | grep -i Rpc`

The out put is like `
1) RpcEptMapper    5) RpcLocator     9) (RPC)         13) Procedure
2) "RPC            6) "Remote       10) Locator"      14) Call
3) Endpoint        7) Procedure     11) RpcSs         15) (RPC)"
4) Mapper"         8) Call          12) "Remote
#?`

But, it should be something like`
1)  RpcEptMapper            "RPC Endpoint Mapper"
2) RpcLocator              "Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Locator"
3) RpcSs                   "Remote Procedure Call (RPC)"
#?`

Comment: I can't tell if the output is multiple lines or not in a comment; add the *exact* output to your question. Are those numbers part of the output?

Comment: You're showing the output of *your* code, not the output  from `net rpc service list` that you are reading and storing in the array.

Comment: Updated that one as well.

Comment: OK, the `readarray` command I added to my answer should accommodate that.

Comment: it has syntax issues
readarray -t services <<(run_net_rpc service list | grep -i Rpc)

Comment: Modified it to
readarray -t services <'run_net_rpc service list | grep -i Rpc'

ERROR:

run_net_rpc service list | grep -i Rpc: No such file or directory

Comment: Well, yes, because that's the wrong syntax; you need `< <(...)` (and not `<<(...)`, which is what it looks like in your comment).

Comment: versions.sh: line 34: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
versions.sh: line 34: `readarray -t services < <(run_net_rpc service list | grep -i Rpc)'

Comment: How are you running the script? It looks like you're using `sh version.sh` instead of `bash version.sh`.

Comment: my shebang says to use bash
either of the cases error is same.

Comment: That's irrelevant if you run it as `sh version.sh`; the shebang is only used if you run the script as a command, not when you pass the file as an argument to an explicit shell.